# How to use live timer on UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift

I implemented a countdown timer on cell in `UICollectionView` and I get time from a webservice, but it shows static time when I go back and comes again in `UICollectionView` the class time decreases according to the web service time left.

But I want to show it live every time it decreases with one second, any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ManageObjectCollectionViewCell
    revealTime  = getRevealtime[indexPath.section].objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! Int             
    minutes = revealTime / 60           
    seconds = revealTime % 60
    cell.HourLabel.text =  "0"
    cell.MinLabel.text = NSString(string: "\(minutes)" ) as String  
    cell.sec.text = NSString(string: "\(seconds)" ) as String
}
```

Comment: not really clear. can you try explaining better with example ?

Comment: Do you have an `NSTimer` object or other timer to trigger when the update needs to happen - (either fetching a new time from the web service, or calculating it based on information you already have).   After a new time is fetched you would reload the cell at the specified index, or reload all the cells (depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

```
    let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    //Find the difference between current time and start time.
    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    //calculate the hours in elapsed time.
    let hours = UInt8(elapsedTime / 3600.0)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(hours) * 3600)


    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

    //find out the fraction of milliseconds to be displayed.
   // let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)

    //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let hourss = String(format: "%02d", hours)

    //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel
    lblDisplayTime.text = "\(hourss):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"
```

use this code